# Seeding thousands of records in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, migration, production-environment, seed

I have several tables that need to be populated when I move my project to production, each of these tables has several thousand rows.  I have the data stored in a CSV file now, but using the seed.rb file seems like it would be cumbersome because the data from my CSV file would have to be formatted to meet the seed.rb format.  If this were only a handful of rows, it wouldn't such a problem.  What would be the best/easiest way to get this data loaded?

Comment: Which DB system are you using? There may be some non-rails specific options we can suggest.

Comment: It's going to MySql or PostgreSQL, not sure which just yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably use a little custom script and the [faster_csv gem](https://github.com/JEG2/faster_csv) which has good tools to parse .csv files quickly. Then you can map the fields to model attributes.

I would implement this via TDD as model methods and use ActiveRecords's create method to instantiate instances. While this is slower than writing SQL straight out, it's safer in that your data will run through all the model validations and you have a better confidence in the data integrity.

Flushing out data integrity issues from legacy data import up front will save you a lot of trouble later.

Comment: Thanks, I took a look at faster_csv and I think that will work fine.  It's a little more work than I was looking for, but I think you're right...With the model validation included it will lead to more confidence in the data integrity.

Answer (score 0):

If I were doing this using MySQL, I'd use MySQL's load data function, like

load data infile '/my/rails/project/data.csv' replace into table table_name fields terminated by '**field_terminator**' lines terminated by '**line_terminator**';

If the tables' designs do not change frequently, you could put a such a statement into a perl, ruby, or shell script.

Answer (score 0):

Like others have mentioned many db's have bulk load support.  But if your looking for a Rails style solution; ar-extensions has bulk insert

- http://rorstuff.blogspot.com/2010/05/activerecord-bulk-insertion-of-data-in.html
- https://github.com/zdennis/ar-extensions

You also can checkout ActiveWarehouse

- https://github.com/zdennis/ar-extensions

Comment: FYI (and mine) it looks like ar-extensions has been replaced with [activerecord-import](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import#readme)

Answer (score 0):

[fast_seeder](https://github.com/greyblake/fast_seeder) gem will help you. It populates database from CSV files using multiple inserts and supports different DB adapters

Answer (score 0):

As most of the answers are outdated, this gem will help you: https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import.

E.g. if you have a collection of books, you can use:

```
Book.import(books)
```

It will execute only one SQL statement.

The gem also works with associations.